# SQLAlchemy - How can I make eager loading count property

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I want to make a property for model which contains count.

Since I always need the property, I want to make query with `JOIN` like `sqlalchemy.orm.relationship` with `lazy='joined'`

For example, I defined models like following

```
import sqlalchemy as s, func
from sqlalchemy.orm import relatioship

# ...

class Foo(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'foo'
    id = s.Column(s.Integer, primary_key=True)
    bar_id = s.Column(s.Integer, s.ForeignKey('bar.id'))
    bar = relationship('Bar')


class Bar(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'bar'
    id = s.Column(s.Integer, primary_key=True)

    @property
    def foo_count(self):
        return Foo.query.filter_by(bar=self).count()
```

When I access to property `foo_count`, then it will send query to DBMS.

Since I always access to this property, I want to load it eagerly the counting property like this

```
# Not session.query(Bar, func.count(Foo.id)).join(Foo) ...
bar = Bar.query.first()
```

SQL will be like this

```
SELECT id, COUNT(Foo.id)
FROM bar 
INNER JOIN foo
    ON bar.id = foo.id
```

Then `bar.foo_count` will not occur SQL query.

How can I make a property like `foo_count`?

Answer (score 17):

I solved it by using  `sqlalchemy.orm.column_property`

I replaced the `foo_count` by following

```
import sqlalchemy as s, func, select
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, column_property

# ...

class Foo(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'foo'
    id = s.Column(s.Integer, primary_key=True)
    bar_id = s.Column(s.Integer, s.ForeignKey('bar.id'))
    bar = relationship('Bar')


class Bar(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'bar'
    id = s.Column(s.Integer, primary_key=True)

    foo_count = column_property(
        select([func.count(Foo.id)])
        .where(Foo.bar_id == id)
    )
```

Comment: Thanks. For other readers, see the discussion of 'column_property' here: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/mapped_sql_expr.html

Answer (score 7):

Please take a look at the [Hybrid Attribute](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/extensions/hybrid.html#correlated-subquery-relationship-hybrid) extension.

Your object model will look similar to the below:

```
class Foo(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'foo'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    bar_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('bar.id'))
    bar = relationship('Bar')

class Bar(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'bar'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    @hybrid_property
    def foo_count(self):
        return object_session(self).query(Foo).filter(Foo.bar==self).count()

    @foo_count.expression
    def foo_count(cls):
        return select([func.count(Foo.id)]).where(Foo.bar_id == cls.id).label('foo_count')
```

`foo_count` will not be eagerly loaded, but you can use it in queries like below (both in `SELECT` and in `WHERE` clause:

```
qry = session.query(Bar, Bar.foo_count).filter(Bar.foo_count > 0)
for (bar, bar_foo_count) in qry:
    print bar, bar_foo_count
```

As you can see, the query will return tuples of `(Bar, foo_count)` in just one query, and now you can do what you wish with that.

Comment: Is not there exist way to join without multiple entities in query? I want to do that automatically just like relationship property.

Comment: If you have a large list of `Bar`s that means you would be running the same count query hundreds or thousands of times. I think instead you should write a direct SQL query where you select all the columns of Bar + `count(Foo.id)`, meaning you would need a JOIN query.

Comment: @OzzyTheGiant: this is not actually what happens. Sqlalchemy will generate a query like this `SELECT bar.*, (SELECT count(foo.id) AS count_1 FROM foo WHERE foo.bar_id = bar.id) AS foo_count FROM bar`. As you can see, there is exactly one joined sub-query. In the last query of my answer the sub-select will be repeated 3 times **in the same one query**, which i assume the RDBMS query optimization engine will take care about. The accepted answer solution using `column_property` generates basically the same construct.

Comment: What happens when there is an intermediate table between Foo and Bar? (Like in a M2M relationship)

Comment: @Curtwagner1984 this is explained in [SQLAlchemy’s docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/mapped_sql_expr.html#using-column-property:~:text=For%20a%20column_property()%20that%20refers%20to%20columns%20linked%20from%20a%20many%2Dto%2Dmany%20relationship)