# querying in sqlalchemy, ordering by model method

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

Here is my model

```
class Monkey(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'monkey'
    __table_args__ = (
        db.UniqueConstraint('best_friend'),
    )

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)
    age = db.Column(db.Integer)
    email = db.Column(db.String(128), index=True, unique=True)
    best_friend = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('monkey.id'))
    password = db.Column(db.String(128))
    is_admin = db.Column(db.Boolean)

    def __init__(self, name, age, email, password, best_friend=None, is_admin=False):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.email = email
        self.password = generate_password_hash(password)
        self.best_friend = best_friend
        self.is_admin = is_admin

    def number_friends(self):
        number = Friendship.query.filter_by(monkey=self.id).count()
        return number

    def get_best_friend(self):
        bf = Monkey.query.filter_by(id=self.best_friend).first()
        return bf.name
```

i am trying to make a query to order my monkeys by their number of friends and by their best friends name so i do a query like this:

```
Monkey.query.order_by(Monkey.number_friends()).paginate(page, 5, False)
```

so this wont work for ordering by number of friends, and i get this error:

```
TypeError: number_friends() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Comment: Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20491389/99594. You only have to add `order_by(Bar.foo_count.desc())` to the answer there in order to get ordering working.