# How to set a M2M hybrid count property in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have two tables bound by a M2M relationship. Books and Writers, writers can have many books and books can have many writers.

I want to have a `count` property on both books and writers so I could sort them by, for example, the writer who wrote the most books.

```py
# many to many association table
book_writer_association_table = Table('book_writer_association',Base.metadata,
                                      Column('book_id',ForeignKey('book.id'), primary_key=True),
                                      Column('Writer',ForeignKey('writer.id'), primary_key=True)
)

class Book(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'base'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    writers = relationship(Writer,secondary=book_writer_association_table,back_populates="books")




class Writer(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'writer'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    books = relationship(Book,secondery=book_writer_association_table,back_populates="writers")

    @hybrid_property
    def book_count(self):
        return len(self.books)

    @book_count.expression
    def book_count(cls):
        #what goes here?
```

I tried various approaches like detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20491389/5550624):

```py
class Foo(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'foo'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    bar_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('bar.id'))
    bar = relationship('Bar')

class Bar(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'bar'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    @hybrid_property
    def foo_count(self):
        return object_session(self).query(Foo).filter(Foo.bar==self).count()

    @foo_count.expression
    def foo_count(cls):
        return select([func.count(Foo.id)]).where(Foo.bar_id == cls.id).label('foo_count')
```

However, in this example, there are only two tables and I'm unsure how to achieve a more complicated join here. Another user suggested using `column_property` but I run into exactly the same problem there. I'm unsure how to further add tables to the join.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can customize idea from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20487553/sqlalchemy-how-can-i-make-eager-loading-count-property/20491389#20491389) to M2M case. For this you should mention `association_table` in `hybrid_property` instead of `Book` table. So, you eliminate join with `Book` table and simplify your case to One-to-Many relation.

I came up with this solution.

```py
from typing import List

from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey, Integer, String, select, func, create_engine, Table
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import as_declarative
from sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid import hybrid_property
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, object_session, sessionmaker, Session

# Declare models
@as_declarative()
class Base:
    pass

book_writer_association_table = Table('book_writer_association',Base.metadata,
                                      Column('book_id',ForeignKey('book.id'), primary_key=True),
                                      Column('writer_id',ForeignKey('writer.id'), primary_key=True)
)

class Book(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'book'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    writers = relationship("Writer", secondary=book_writer_association_table, back_populates="books")




class Writer(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'writer'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    books = relationship("Book", secondary=book_writer_association_table, back_populates="writers")

    @hybrid_property
    def book_count(self):
        return object_session(self).query(book_writer_association_table).filter(book_writer_association_table.c.writer_id == self.id).count()

    @book_count.expression
    def book_count(cls):
        return select([func.count(book_writer_association_table.c.book_id)]).where(book_writer_association_table.c.writer_id == cls.id).label('book_count')

# Load DB schema
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///sqlite3.db')
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=True, bind=engine)
db: Session = SessionLocal()

# Creating test instances
b1 = Book(name="Book 1")
b2 = Book(name="Book 2")
db.add(b1)
db.add(b2)

w1 = Writer(name="Writer 1")
w2 = Writer(name="Writer 2")
db.add(w1)
db.add(w2)

b1.writers.append(w1)
b1.writers.append(w2)
b2.writers.append(w1)

query = db.query(Writer, Writer.book_count)
print(str(query)) # checking query
print()
writers: List[Writer] = query.all() # testing query
for writer, book_count in writers:
    print(f"{writer.name}: {book_count}")
```

Result:

```
> Writer 1: 2
> Writer 2: 1
```

> I'm unsure how to further add tables to the join.

SQL from here `db.query(Writer, Writer.book_count)` looks clean, without any joins. So, I think you shouldn't have any problems with subsequent joins.

```
> SELECT writer.id AS writer_id, writer.name AS writer_name, (SELECT count(book_writer_association.book_id) AS count_1 
> FROM book_writer_association 
> WHERE book_writer_association.writer_id = writer.id) AS book_count 
> FROM writer
```

**Edit**: If you need join `Book` table to provide additional filtering you can do it like this. Here I filtered book with price less than 150

```
from typing import List

from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey, Integer, String, select, func, create_engine, Table
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import as_declarative
from sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid import hybrid_property
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, object_session, sessionmaker, Session

# Declare models
@as_declarative()
class Base:
    pass

book_writer_association_table = Table('book_writer_association',Base.metadata,
                                      Column('book_id',ForeignKey('book.id'), primary_key=True),
                                      Column('writer_id',ForeignKey('writer.id'), primary_key=True)
)

class Book(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'book'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    price = Column(Integer)
    writers = relationship("Writer", secondary=book_writer_association_table, back_populates="books")




class Writer(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'writer'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    books = relationship("Book", secondary=book_writer_association_table, back_populates="writers")

    @hybrid_property
    def book_count(self):
        return (
            object_session(self)
                .query(book_writer_association_table)
                .join(Book, Book.id == book_writer_association_table.c.book_id)
                .filter(book_writer_association_table.c.writer_id == self.id)
                .filter(Book.price > 150)
                .count()
        )

    @book_count.expression
    def book_count(cls):
        # return select([func.count(book_writer_association_table.c.book_id)]).where(book_writer_association_table.c.writer_id == cls.id).label('book_count')
        #
        return (
            select([func.count(book_writer_association_table.c.book_id)])
                .join(Book, Book.id == book_writer_association_table.c.book_id)
                .where(book_writer_association_table.c.writer_id == cls.id)
                .filter(Book.price > 150)
                .label('book_count')
        )

# Load DB schema
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///sqlite3.db')
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=True, bind=engine)
db: Session = SessionLocal()

# Creating test instances
b1 = Book(name="Book 1", price=100)
b2 = Book(name="Book 2", price=200)
db.add(b1)
db.add(b2)

w1 = Writer(name="Writer 1")
w2 = Writer(name="Writer 2")
db.add(w1)
db.add(w2)

b1.writers.append(w1)
b1.writers.append(w2)
b2.writers.append(w1)

query = db.query(Writer, Writer.book_count)
print(str(query)) # checking query
print()
writers: List[Writer] = query.all() # testing query
for writer, book_count in writers:
    print(f"{writer.name}: {book_count}")
```

query:

```
SELECT writer.id              AS writer_id,
       writer.name            AS writer_name,
       (SELECT count(book_writer_association.book_id) AS count_1
        FROM book_writer_association
                 JOIN book ON book.id = book_writer_association.book_id
        WHERE book_writer_association.writer_id = writer.id
          AND book.price > ?) AS book_count
FROM writer
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a great idea! But how would one go about it though if there is more than one association table or if you can't get away with only referencing the association table?
For example if instead of counting the amount of books an author has, you need to count something else where you must also have the join to the book table. For example, if you want the property to count only books that have more than 100 pages.

Comment: @Curtwagner1984 I've adjusted my answer to your case, plz check